# Confused about probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

The problem I'm trying to solve should be solvable by Binomial distribution. However I did not get the right answer, so now I have no idea how to proceed.

Problem : An emergency center receives 1200 calls a month. Out of these calls 0,15 % are misplaced. What is the probability that in the next month 2 calls are misplaced.

And by Binomial distribution I of course mean -

Pr(X=k)=(n!/(k!(n-k)!)) pk (1-p)n-k

The answer is 0,268. My textbook does not really elaborate a lot on this subject, so anything that will help me towards the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/139123 to see how to make this question readable.

Comment: For exactly $2$ calls misplaced we use your expression, $n=1200$, $k=2$, $p=0.0015$. Or use the Poisson approximation, $\lambda=(1200)(0.0015)=1.8$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly, you have to estimate $p$. Secondly you plug $p$ and $k=2$ into your formula.
The mean of binomial distribution is $n p$. We know that mean is $0.0015$. So your answer is
$$
C_{1200}^2 p^2*(1-p)^{1198}
$$
$$
C_{1200}^2=1200!/(2!*1198!)=600*1199=719400
$$
$$
p^2=0.0015^2=0.0000225
$$
$$
(1-p)^{1198}=0.1656
$$

So $719400*0.0000225*0.1656=0.267$